# Create either Sankey diagram or burst chart based on user input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sankey-diagram, sunburst-diagram, networkd3

I need to create either a burstchart or a sankey based on the user input at the same place in the frontend. The code that creates either of the two charts are nearly same. So I was trying to return either the burstchart or the Sankey diagram to the output variable based on the user input.

However, the render functions are different for both and hence this is posing a problem. Any help would be great.

The below code is not reproducible, but should give an idea.

```
Ui.R 
sankeyNetworkOutput("sankey_plot",width=1000, height=300) 
server.R
output$sankey_plot = renderSankeyNetwork({
})
```

Comment: use `conditionalPanel()` to display a certain output based on some condition, such as a user selection.

Comment: You could use `renderUI`